# Spectral analysis with RF signal generator

Tags: rf, signal, spectrum-analyzer

I need the spectral analysis of an LC circuit which oscillates in UHF band. I have a rough idea about its resonance peak but I need to observe it. As equipment, I have at my disposal Aeroflex 3020 RF signal generator, Aeroflex 3035 RF digitizer. Each uses a 3010 RF synthesizer as local oscillator.

My question is that, can I use this setup for spectral analysis purpose ? If yes, what would be the strategy to follow ? Should I sweep the frequency range via script? Should I send signals which contain many harmonics to excite the circuit ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What Q do you expect?

Comment: Can you use the sweep trigger to start the digitizer and synchronize a frequency vs time FFT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any source/receiver pair like that as a scalar network analyser. Just program them to the same frequency, and they'll give you a measurement of gain at that frequency. Step the frequencies over a range to get gain versus frequency vector, and plot it for a spectrum.